# Factors to find weight painting formula for Auto-Rigging

Tags: algorithm, opengl, animation, artificial-intelligence, robotics

I'm trying to re-implement Auto-rigging for human skeletons. (similar to Blender and Mixamo's)

For each vertex in the human skin, I've to find the joints that affect this vertex. (I could do this.)

Now I've to find how much each joint should affect this vertex. (assigning weights for each vertex)

The human skin can be represented by an array of traingles each containing 3 vertices and the joints can be represented by array of vertices.

Note that each vertex can be affected by n number of joints(n>=1) which means no vertex should remain un-weighted.

I can manage to construct a connected graph of the skin. I don't know how to assign weights for each vertex from this graph. Help/Suggestions?

Comment: *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: Isn't a connected graph(without duplicate vertices) a reduction of the problem? Maya/Blender's Auto-Rig has problems in assigning weights just because the graph is not connected. I'm just a beginner in math and animation and I don't know on what basis I should give weights.

Comment: I still think it's too big. Just my opinion, though, perhaps someone else will find the time and will to answer you.

Comment: I don't need the exact solution. All I need is some help to move on. For now I need the factors to be considered for weighing.

Answer (score 0):

This may explain your case. The algorithm is too big. For me it explains the things well. Have a look

http://people.csail.mit.edu/ibaran/papers/2007-SIGGRAPH-Pinocchio.pdf

Comment: That looks like an interesting paper. I think section 4 (Skin Attachment) is relevant to the question.